# Subdomain Url Rewrite in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewrite-module

I have an MVC Website published using Azure Websites.

I need to redirect a subdomain to an external website.

I tried to use url-rewrite but it seems not working. Is there something wrong with my url rewrite module?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to Facebook" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(facebook\.)(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.facebook.com/myprofile" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Hey, have you solved you problem? I am about to try to do the same in Azure.

Comment: I do it on the my domain setting instead